# Intersection of two lists containing Object types in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, intersection

How to find the intersection of two lists containing tuples of float values in Python?
For example:

```
A = [(1.1,2.2),(3.3,4.4),(5.5,6.6)]
B = [(1.1,2.2),(7.7,8.8),(3.3,4.4)]
```

I need

```
A intersection B = [(1.1,2.2),(3.3,4.4)]
```

**Update:**

My bad. Thanks for the response but I there was a misconception in my understanding.

The question should be

For example:

```
A = [Point(1.1,2.2),Point(3.3,4.4),Point(5.5,6.6)]
B = [Point(1.1,2.2),Point(7.7,8.8),Point(3.3,4.4)]
```

I need

```
A intersection B = [Point(1.1,2.2),Point(3.3,4.4)]
```

where Point is my python class containing two float variables as shown

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, a_, b_):
        self.a = a_
        self.b = b_
```

Comment: Does `Point` define the `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods?

Comment: Please include the definition of the `Point` class in your question and change its title.

Answer (score 5):

If order does not matter use `set.intersection`:

```
A = [(1.1,2.2),(3.3,4.4),(5.5,6.6)]
B = [(1.1,2.2),(7.7,8.8),(3.3,4.4)]

print(set(A).intersection(B))
set([(3.3, 4.4), (1.1, 2.2)])
```

Or make B a set and iterate over A keeping common elements:

```
st = set(B)

print([ele for ele in A if ele in st ])

[(1.1, 2.2), (3.3, 4.4)]
```

If you are looking for objects with the same attribute values:

```
A = [Point(1.1,2.2),Point(3.3,4.4),Point(5.5,6.6)]
B = [Point(1.1,2.2),Point(7.7,8.8),Point(3.3,4.4)]


st = set((p.a,p.b) for p in B)

print([p for p in A if (p.a,p.b) in st])
```

Or create a hash method in your class:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, a_, b_):
        self.a = a_
        self.b = b_

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.a, self.b))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a, self.b == other.a,other.b

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

A = [Point(1.1,2.2),Point(3.3,4.4),Point(5.5,6.6)]
B = [Point(1.1,2.2),Point(7.7,8.8),Point(3.3,4.4)]


print(set(A).intersection(B))
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look and help me. I will continue my research on it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

Intersect `my_list_01` and `my_list_02`, and store the result in `intersected_list`

```
intersected_list= [item for item in my_list_01 if item in my_list_02]
```